# custom order of a python list

Tags: python

i'm using **glob.glob()** to get a list of files from a directory.

the result is this list. there is a way i can sort it using the int part of the filename?

```
['export_p-01.xml',
 'export_p-02.xml',
 'export_p-03.xml',
 'export_p-04.xml',
 'export_p-05.xml',
 'export_p-06.xml',
 'export_p-07.xml',
 'export_p-08.xml',
 'export_p-09.xml',
 'export_p-10.xml',
 'export_p-100.xml',
 'export_p-101.xml',
 'export_p-102.xml',
 'export_p-103.xml',
 'export_p-104.xml',
 'export_p-105.xml',
 'export_p-106.xml',
 'export_p-107.xml',
 'export_p-108.xml',
 'export_p-109.xml',
 'export_p-11.xml',
]
```

Comment: This question was in my final exam , I couldn't solve it there either lol.

Comment: The duplicate is specifically asking about Python 3, but the answers cover both Python 2 and 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, with a custom lambda for using as key:

```
In [1]: l = ['export_p-01.xml', ...]

In [2]: sorted(l, key = lambda x: int(x.split(".")[0].split("-")[-1]))
Out[2]: 
['export_p-01.xml',
 'export_p-02.xml',
 'export_p-03.xml',
 'export_p-04.xml',
 'export_p-05.xml',
 'export_p-06.xml',
 'export_p-07.xml',
 'export_p-08.xml',
 'export_p-09.xml',
 'export_p-10.xml',
 'export_p-11.xml',
 'export_p-100.xml',
 'export_p-101.xml',
 'export_p-102.xml',
 'export_p-103.xml',
 'export_p-104.xml',
 'export_p-105.xml',
 'export_p-106.xml',
 'export_p-107.xml',
 'export_p-108.xml',
 'export_p-109.xml']
```